# Menu icons don't appear, ics 4.0.3

Tags: android, xml

I was trying to add an icon to my menu item in xml by adding this line

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
```

in `<item>` and it didn't work.

I've also tried put my image in drawable folder, try to display it by:

```
android:icon="@drawable/my_image"
```

Didn't work too, icons didn't appear in menu.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If by "menu", you mean the action overflow area of the action bar, it does not show icons, and so you are not doing anything wrong. Icons are only used for toolbar buttons in the action bar.

Comment: @user1367471: That is the action overflow area of the action bar, as seen on a device with a MENU button. It does not show icons, and so you are not doing anything wrong.

Comment: Is it possible to add an icon there? Something like this bluetooth, picassa, messaging icons: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

Comment: @user1367471: "Is it possible to add an icon there?" -- AFAIK, no (otherwise, your icons would be showing up already). What you are referring to is `ShareActionProvider`, which is a custom widget added to the action bar and is not a menu (in the classic Android definition of "menu").